# Random Walk: Quantiles, average and maximal walk

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, random-walk

As a statistics newbie I'm interested in the random walk, especially in a random walk with an underlying normal distribution where the variance of the process is known. For these special cases I tried to find out how I could calculate the expected distance travelled, the expected distance of the maximal walk as well as quantiles of the resulting normal distribution for given walking times n. Would be very happy if you'd help! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the expected distance traveled, maximal walk distance, and quantiles?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have a random walk where each step numbers from a normal distributions with mean 0 and known variance are sampled. And I'd like to know what "drift" away from the starting point I can expect on average and maximal after n steps, as well as the xth-quantile.